# How do I list cards for a specified customer using Balanced API?

Tags: rest, balanced-payments

I am using PHP to try to get the card from Balanced.

I can get all the cards using

```
$marketplace = Balanced\Marketplace::mine();
$cards = $marketplace->cards->query()->all();
```

I can look though the $cards array and in each card object I find a values like this
uri : /v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP4K6K0PWGyPtXL4LZ42sQSb/cards/CC5N3HHUDrAyvhNwQOoUd3UX 
this appears to be formatted as
"/v1/marketplaces/MARKETPLACE ID/cards/CARD ID"

However I only want the cards for a specific customer so I tried

```
$customer = Balanced\Customer::get("/v1/customers/CU6vs1tjxBtifgTuzKjCGtVS");
$cards = $customer->cards->query()->all();
```

Now when I look thought the card object the format of the uri has changed
uri : /v1/customers/CU6vs1tjxBtifgTuzKjCGtVS/cards/CC5N3HHUDrAyvhNwQOoUd3UX
So it gives the uri as
"/v1/customers/CUSTOMER ID/cards/CARD ID"

Question, can I use this customer based uri for all card functions such as charging and deleting?
Or, if I have to use the marketplaces format do I rebuild the URI (which balanced warns against) or is there some why I can get the uri in it's proper format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of those uri's.  They are just using different endpoints, but will result in the same successful transactions.

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned that balance stress using the URI and not modifying it but then there turns out to be multiple URI for the same thing.  Especially given that URI is an acronym.